# Frama-c cannot prove validity of buffer pointer of type other than `char*`

Tags: pointers, frama-c

Consider the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*@
  requires \valid(p+(0..n-1));
  requires \valid(fp);
 */
void f(/*unsigned*/ char *p, size_t n, FILE *fp)
{
    fread(p, 1, n, fp);
}
```

Frama-c can prove that the pre-conditions to `fread` are met. However, with `unsigned` restored, frama-c fails to see the obvious fact that `\valid((char*)p+(0..n-1))` holds. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the conversion from `unsigned char *` in `f` to `char *` in the pre-condition of `fread` is confusing the WP plug-in of Frama-C. When using `-wp-out foo` to get the files given to the external provers in directory `foo/`, I get the following goal in Alt-Ergo's syntax:

```
goal f_call_fread_pre_valid_ptr_block:
  forall i : int.
  forall t : int farray.
  forall t_1 : (addr,int) farray.
  forall a_2,a_1,a : addr.
  (region(a_1.base) <= 0) ->
  (region(a_2.base) <= 0) ->
  linked(t) ->
  sconst(t_1) ->
  is_uint32(i) ->
  valid_rw(t, a_2, 2) ->
  valid_rw(t, shift_uint8(a_1, 0), i) ->
  valid_rw(t, shift_sint8(a, 0), i)
```

Note in particular that the hypothesis (i.e. the `requires` of `f`) mentions variable `a_1`, while the goal (i.e. the `requires` of `fread` that we are trying to prove), mentions variable `a`, and that there is absolutely nothing tying `a_1` and `a` together.

I'd tend to see that as a bug, but I'm not expert in WP's internals. You might want to report that on [Frama-C's BTS](https://bts.frama-c.com).